# Wrapping 2 lines at at time in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have thought about this and I'm not sure if it's possible with a CSS only solution, although I'm not even sure how I'd do it with JS.

Given text like the following:

```
123456789012345678901234567890
This is a whole bunch of words
123456789012345678901234567890
Yes it is yes it is oh yes....
```

And having a screen so narrow that only the first 20 chars can fit. How can I wrap the text so that it displays like this:

```
1234567890123456789
This is a whole bun
01234567890
ch of words
12345678901234567890
Yes it is yes it is 
1234567890
oh yes....
```

That is, wrapping 2 lines at a time. Typical wrapping rules will give me the wrong result:

```
1234567890123456789
01234567890
This is a whole bun
ch of words
1234567890123456789
01234567890
Yes it is yes it is
 oh yes....
```

Comment: Javascript seems needed with this form of conditional logic. And a "fixed" font, something like "Courier".

Comment: You could if the text is known ahead of time so you can prepare the numbers ahead of time. If unknown ahead of time, you will need something (not necessarily javascript and not necessarily on the client side) to, at minimum, generate the numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placing the texts above each other and using a big line-height can approximate this:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 2.4em; /* twice the font-size*/
  padding-top: 1.2em; /* equal to font-size*/
  font-family: monospace;
  
  /* to illustrate */
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  resize: horizontal;
  word-break: break-all; /* omit this to keep full words */
}

.box div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</div>
  This is a whole bunch of words Yes it is yes it is oh yes....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
:root {
  --font-size: 16px;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 22.5ex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
}
div > pre {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: var(--font-size);
  line-height: calc(var(--font-size) * 2 * 1.2);
}
div > pre:first-child {
  position: absolute;
}
div > pre:last-child {
  padding-top: calc(var(--font-size) * 1.2);
}
```

```html
<div>
<pre>123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</pre>
<pre>This is a whole bunch of words Yes it is yes it is oh yes...</pre>
</div>
```

Unfortunately there's still some issues with this. There's no way to get the character width in CSS so, without javascript, you're left to guessing.