# How to wrap a whole group of elements on the next line when screen gets smaller using CSS?

Tags: html, css

On big screens, like desktops, it would look like this:
[image]

But in smaller screens or when zoomed in, I want my multiple lines to wrap like this:
[image]

I tried this:

```css
.tab__set {
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-family: monospace;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.tab {
  min-height: 1.2rem;
  display: block;
  white-space: wrap;
}
```

```html
<span class="tab__set">
  <span class="tab">e|------------------------|----------------------------|----------------------|-------------</span>
  <span class="tab">B|------------------------|-------2h3p2----5-----5--2--|------2-----2-----2---|---3-----3---</span>
  <span class="tab">G|------------------------|----2--------2--4-----4--2--|------2-----2-----2---|---2-----2---</span>
  <span class="tab">D|------------------------|----------------------------|----------------------|-------------</span>
  <span class="tab">A|------------------------|-0--------------------------|----------------------|-------------</span>
  <span class="tab">E|--------------------0h2-|----------------4--4-----2--|---2-----2--0--0-----0|---2--2-----2</span>
</span>
```

Above, I tried using `white-space: wrap;` but the result is not what I desire. It doesn't wrap as a whole set of tabs like what it did on the second image above. Instead, it just wraps as individual elements.

Then I tried using `white-space: nowrap;` and of course that doesn't work because it will not show all the tabs unless I scroll horizontally. I don't know how to make multiple elements go on a new line as a whole group. Please help.

---

Comment: Make the parent flex and give it flex-wrap property.

Comment: @TemaniAfif interesting approach, although probably not ideal in terms of semantics / accessibility? (Not that there was that much of either here to begin with, with the given example structure. But then I have never had to implement anything like this in HTML, so off the top of my head I wouldn’t know what a proper HTML structure for this kind of data would look like either.)

Comment: @CBroe yes I doubt semantics or accessibility are needed here since I don't know how the browser should understand such think (I am not even able as a human to understand what is this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65347763/8620333) and in case the number of lines is known you can approximate like below:

```css
.tab__set {
  --s:1.2em;
  --n:6;
  
  font-size: var(--s);
  line-height: calc((var(--n) + 1)*var(--s)); 
  font-family: monospace;
  position:relative;
  
   /* to illustrate */
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  resize: horizontal;
  word-break:break-all;
}
.tab__set .tab {
  display:block;
  transform:translateY(calc(-1*var(--n)*var(--s)/2))
}

.tab__set .tab:not(:first-child) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.tab__set .tab:nth-child(2) {top:calc(1*var(--s));}
.tab__set .tab:nth-child(3) {top:calc(2*var(--s));}
.tab__set .tab:nth-child(4) {top:calc(3*var(--s));}
.tab__set .tab:nth-child(5) {top:calc(4*var(--s));}
.tab__set .tab:nth-child(6) {top:calc(5*var(--s));}
/*.tab__set .tab:nth-child(N) {top:calc((N - 1)*var(--s));}
```

```html
<div class="tab__set">
  <span class="tab">e|------------------------|----------------------------|----------------------|------------</span>
  <span class="tab">B|------------------------|-------2h3p2----5-----5--2--|------2-----2-----2---|---3-----3---</span>
  <span class="tab">G|------------------------|----2--------2--4-----4--2--|------2-----2-----2---|---2-----2---</span>
  <span class="tab">D|------------------------|----------------------------|----------------------|-------------</span>
  <span class="tab">A|------------------------|-0--------------------------|----------------------|-------------</span>
  <span class="tab">E|--------------------0h2-|----------------4--4-----2--|---2-----2--0--0-----0|---2--2-----2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Temani! Your solution is awesome! But I've noticed while I was slowly dragging the resizer that sometimes the lines don't break equally. This is important because the tabs should be in the right sequence on all different screen sizes. You think there's a solution for this?

Comment: @Zedd adjst the font size unti you get the perfect one that will not produce this and probably try to find a better monospace font